# Why is this for loop not printing anything?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

making a simple algo with two classes. Trying to figure out why it won't print anything. Probably something obvious, but I cannot see it.
The program takes 2 inputs, a String and an Int. It repeats the string the amount of times the int equals.

**MAIN:**

```
public class Main { 
 public static void main (String[]args) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Enter the string you want to repeat: ");
  String str = input.nextLine();
  input.nextLine();//Clear scanner memory

  System.out.print("Enter the amount of times you want it to repeat: ");
  int repeat = input.nextInt();

  references.repeat(str, repeat);
 }
}
```

**SECOND CLASS:**

```
public void repeat(String str, int n) {
 for (int repeatNum = n; repeatNum > 0; repeatNum--) {
  System.out.println(str);
 }          
}
```

Comment: What values are you inputting?

Comment: Code you've given looks good

Comment: If it's possible, could you provide a more complete code sample (one that could be run without any additions or modifications)? It's a bit hard to read if that's not provided, and there may be a detail we can't realize without it.

Comment: I'm inputting a string and an int. It doesn't output the string at all.

Comment: That is obvious. But with what values?

Comment: Looks like the perfect time to learn about breakpoints.

Comment: I bet the `repeat` value ends up as `0` somehow.

Comment: Canhazbits... you're probably right... idk how though

Comment: Is it even printing the second prompt?  Or just waiting to get another line in the scanner?  You don't need that extra `nextLine()`.

Comment: Are you importing your second class?  Where are you instantiating `references` (since `repeat` isn't a `static` method).  And again, WHAT values are you inputting?  "A string and an int" doesn't describe what you're inputting.  Unless you're literally typing "an int", which doesn't contain a `nextInt` for your `scanner`.

Comment: I need the nextLine() to clear memory. It skips the lines if I don't have it.

Comment: I'm inputting "ryan" and "3" without quotes

Comment: Are you `importing` your second class?  Where is `references` declared and instantiated?

Comment: Remove the second `nextLine()`, you don't have to 'clear scanner memory' or whatever that means.

Comment: Your code works if I just add the method to a class and don't use `references` on the call in `main`. Note your behavior on "clearing" the scanner; it waits for me to enter!

Comment: I think the most important thing here is, learn to use a debugger. Heck, even just print the values out before you go into your repeat loop

Comment: Is this actually ALL of your `main`, or is there something else before this?  Like reading another number first, or something?

Comment: It just skips over that input.nextLine(); part. If I pre-set the string, it will repeat to the specified amount.

Comment: Added input.nextLine(); above System.out.print("Enter the string you want to repeat: ");

It was running for you guys because I didn't put the rest of the code above it. I had a previous Scanner.nextLine statement. I needed to clear the memory of the scanner.

Comment: Somewhere above what you've shown are attempting to clean the scanner with `nextInt()`? The way you're using `nextLine()` isn't useful. I can remove them from your code, add more - whatever, and the only difference it will make is having to press enter to continue. Trying the same with `nextInt()` is troublesome. Also, it sounds like the code that needs to be looked at is above this. Sounds like that's what's causing the issue.

Comment: Are you saying that you asked us all to help you find a bug, but you deliberately left out the part of the code where the bug was?  If you want people to help you, don't mess them around like this.

Answer (score 1):

Since the previous answer was deleted:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the string you want to repeat: ");
        String str = input.nextLine();


        System.out.print("Enter the amount of times you want it to repeat: ");
        int repeat = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println(str);
        System.out.println(repeat);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the string you want to repeat: dererer
Enter the amount of times you want it to repeat: 5

dererer
5
```

If you're not having this output, it's because of a localized issue that is not detailed in your post.

If you do exactly this and you still don't get the output as expected: edit your post and **detail** the **exact** steps you take.